# Azure API Apps - How to define Login Policy

Tags: api, azure, gateway

We are developing a ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 application and want to use the new Azure Api Apps. So have followed Brady's tutorials, but when I try and access the service on Azure I get bounced at the default gateway saying...

> {   "status": 400,   "source":
>   "https://default-web-northeuropef54b46974f064fc0b30c72928d0d7443.azurewebsites.net/login/federated?service=SceneStealer.Web.Api",
>   "message": "No default login policy set, configure gateway auth policy
>   first." }

So I went through the article to secure your webservices with Azure Active Directory thinking this may trigger it.... but no... it didn't make any difference. I can't find any articles or anything on how to set a default login policy for an Azure gateway and have been struggling with this for a day now.. so any suggestions or pointers to articles would be greatly appreciated!

App URL: [My Azure](https://microsoft-apiapp396a02a3d381482286f50068af54d64c.azurewebsites.net/api/conference/get)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. My Azure AD had my Microsoft Live account user. But I figured that maybe because I'm testing on my personal laptop and my laptop's user is actually not the Microsoft Live account.

So at Azure AD, I created another user of the same name as my personal laptop account, on domain yourname.onmicrosoft.com. Then go to the API site's /login/aad and login as that account. It seems to authenticate through, though I now get a new error saying "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."